# OLS Regression with statsmodels giving many coefficients

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a simple regression on encryption time for a given datasize from a dataset. I'm a beginner with python and statsmodels but I think I'm getting strange results with OLS regression since it provides me a coefficient for every datasize like :

```
DataSize[T.1024] 0.0001
DataSize[T.1040] 0.0003
DataSize[T.1056] 0.0004
DataSize[T.1072] 0.0006
DataSize[T.1088] 0.0007
```

here is the code I developed:

```
    encrypt_key_16 = select_total_encrypt_time.loc[select_total_encrypt_time['KeySize'] == 16]
    y4, X4 = dmatrices('Measure ~ DataSize', data=encrypt_key_16, return_type='dataframe')
    mod4 = sm.OLS(y4, X4)
    result4 = mod4.fit()
```

Am I doing something wrong ?

Thank you in advance for your answer.

Comment: it look like `DataSize` is interpreted as categorical. Make sure it has a numeric dtype, e.g. float64. int should also be fine but not string or similar.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately DataSize matrix X4 as indeed type float64. So I don't think that's the problem here.

Comment: did you check `encrypt_key_16.dtypes` or `np.asarray(encrypt_key_16['DataSize']).dtype` ?

Answer (score 0):

Okay I think I found what the problem is. When I print the dataframe X4 I'm getting the following output:

[Output when printing X4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/au61i.png)

So I need to somehow make it only one column of DataSize.